# HTTP Verb Tampering solution

Tags: java, web-services

HTTP Verb Misconfiguration : 
can you suggest me measures how we can prevent HTTP Verb Tampering in a web application when we have GET and POST methods implemented in our web applications.

Comment: Please share the code in question to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a page [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Verb_Tampering_(OTG-INPVAL-003)) maintained by the Open Web Application Security Project on testing for HTTP verb tampering. Basically, you use a utility to send a request using each method (a.k.a. verb) and check that the request is handled safely. The key point made on that page is:

> Although each HTTP method can potentially return different results, there is only a single valid result for all methods other than GET and POST. The web server should either ignore the request completely or return an error. Any other response indicates a test failure as the server is responding to methods/verbs that are unnecessary. These methods should be disabled.